# while loop in the PHP code excecuting infinite times

Tags: php, while-loop, strpos

```
<?php
$string="I am Azizul hakim.I am a student.I am feeling good today";
$find="am";
$i=0;
$find_length=strlen($find);
while($i<strlen($string))
{
    $pos=strpos($string,$find,$i);
    echo $pos;
    $i=$pos+$find_length;
}
?>
```

The php code is executing infinite times.Although the limit is restricted by specifying the string length of the string.Why it is executing infinite times?

Comment: While not familiar with PHP think about unmet condition of '$i=$pos+$find_length;'

Comment: please debug your code before you post. strpos returns false when your remaining string doesn't contain any $find. so it will loop back to 0 + $find_length => 2, A simple fix would be a `break` if `$pos === false`

Comment: Yes I have run that one and it works fine.But what is the problem with this one? @bummi

Comment: OK thanks got it. @Isitar

Comment: I guess that strpos can return negative values, when $i (search offset) grows bigger than length of $string. Add an additional condition to while loop e.g. $i >= 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strpos` returns false, which evaluates to 0, when your remaining `$string` doesn't contain $find and the loop starts over again.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I believe perl compatible regular expression, (pcre), is always the best choice. Why, because you will use only (1) function / method call, and then simple loop to process the result. With string type functions / methods, each time your $needle is found in your $haystack you will need to call another string type function / method to handle the next occurrence of your $needle being found in your $haystack!